# testng folder paths are messed up when ran from an ant

Tags: java, ant, testng

I'm trying to run a test to check if a folder is empty. This is pretty easy, but the problem is that I run it locally and on a server. Locally I run the test and is green, but on the server its ran from an ant so the folder path is messed up.

Locally is something like this: 
C:\Project\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3

I need to check if Folder3 is empty, having a relative path like \Folder1\Folder2\Folder3 .This is working, but on the server where is ran from an ant my path becomes like this

C:\Project\ant\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3

That ant folder becomes part of the base path, and this will mess up my check since i have no Folder3 there. I need a way to specify in code to take the Project as basepath and not the working directory so I can attach \Folder1\Folder2\Folder3 and do my check. Any ideas??

Comment: Your ant build file is in `C:\Project\ant`?

Comment: yes, my ant files are in my project

Comment: So you may look at "basedir" in http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html  In your build file, you can set the `basedir` to be `..` so that your ant build file's working dir is `C:\Project`.